# Есть ли адекватный способ расшифровать текст, зашифрованный в картинку?

Tags: python, алгоритм, шифрование, стеганография

2 года назад я баловался со скриптом шифрования текста в изображение. Недавно обнаружил изображение, в котором зашифрован текст, но рядом не было "ключей" для расшифровки.

Мне интересно, можно ли как-то расшифровать текст из этого изображения?

---

**Алгоритм шифрования:**

1. Текст для зашифровки в картинку предварительно шифруется при помощи библиотеки `cryptography` (`Python`).
2. Для каждого символа из текста выбирается ***случайный неповторяющийся*** пиксель изображения, а затем код его **красного оттенка** заменяется на ASCII-код символа.

   - Пример: Символ `'x'` имеет код `120`. Случайно выбранный пиксель имеет следующие параметры — `R=50, G=155, B=70`. После шифрования пиксель перезапишется с новыми параметрами — `R=120, G=155, B=70`
3. После того, как все символы текста были зашифрованы в пиксели изображения, сохраняется
   картинка и рядом с ней файл с координатами измененных пикселей, **разумеется, в правильном для символов текста порядке, чтобы текст потом можно было обратно расшифровать через `cryptography`**

*Так как я использовал замену только красного оттенка, а не популярный [**метод LSB**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F#:%7E:text=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0.-,%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%20LSB,%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0.), измененная картинка имеет характерные "пятна", так как не у всех пикселей красный оттенок является главным, а замена сильно изменяет цвет.*

---

**Проблема:**

Изображение с зашифрованным текстом есть, а вот файла с ключами-координатами измененных пикселей нет. Однако рядом лежало также оригинальное изображение. Попиксельно сверив эти картинки, я получил все измененные пиксели. А далее проблема — этих пикселей ~`500` штук и для расшифровки текста нужно выставить их в правильном порядке — **иначе в `cryptography` просто не подойдет ключ для расшифровки**

---

**Очевидная идея решения:**

Подставим в формулу размещения без повторений значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где нижнее `500` — число пикселей, а верхнее `500` — это длина одного размещения. По формуле получаем, что есть [**вот столько**](https://calc-best.ru/matematicheskie/faktorial?n=500) возможных комбинаций зашифрованных символов, из которых **только одна** будет верной и расшифруется в текст.

Думаю, очевидно, что ни один комп мне такой перебор не обработает.

---

А есть ли другой способ узнать, какая комбинация верна? "Случайность" выбора пикселя была реализована через встроенную функцию `random.randint`. Может быть есть какой-то способ узнать ключ генератора и воспроизвести этот случайный выбор? *(Возможно написал бред, к сожалению, не до конца разобрался в этой теме)*

Comment: Чтобы воспроизвести случайный выбор, надо его знать, чтобы понять, что вопросизвелся он корректно, а вы не знаете.

Comment: ну и по сути, у вас текст зашифрованный дважды. Даже если вы проверите все 500! вариантов, нет гарании, что только 1 вариант подойдет. Вполне возможно, что будет сотни или тысячи вариантов, которые во что то да расшифровываются.